# InvalidEbXmlMessage error from GetMarketingTextRQ

Tags: sabre

I was trying to use GetMarketingTextRQ service, but got error message "Unable to internalize message".

Please review my logs below.

the request:

[image: request]

the response:

[image: response]

```
<GetMarketingTextRQ version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v1">
    <BrandsMarketingTextRequest>
        <RequestSource clientID="AVL" geoLocation="HDQ" pseudoCityCode="HDQ" requestingCarrierGDS="PG"/>
        <MarketingTextCriteria carrier="PG" language="EN"/>
    </BrandsMarketingTextRequest>
</GetMarketingTextRQ>
```

Comment: Is this error persistent? Would you kindly share the RQ in XML/Text format?

Comment: Hello, thanks for looking into this, plz see the RQ above.

Answer (score 1):

There are some adjustments needing to be made.

Following is a working request:

`<GetMarketingTextRQ version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://stl.sabre.com/Merchandising/v1">
    <BrandsMarketingTextRequest>
        <RequestSource clientID="SHP" geoLocation="BER" pseudoCityCode="XXXX" requestingCarrierGDS="1S"/>
        <MarketingTextCriteria carrier="LX" language="EN"/>
    </BrandsMarketingTextRequest>
</GetMarketingTextRQ>`

You should change:

`clientID="SHP"` - looking for availability is not working
`geoLocation="BER"` - defines the IATA city of your PCC
`pseudoCityCode="XXXX"` - this is the PCC of your account with Sabre not an IATA City
`requestingCarrierGDS="1S"` - this is the GDS of the Airline 1S=Sabre, 1B=Abacus, 1F=Infini, 1J=Axess ( most likely it will be 1S)

Tested this with LX as i know this is a DCA carrier with Sabre. Not sure about PG.